# OptimisticLockException while using - "for update skip locked"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the below calls using JPA native queries using entity manager. My understanding was if we use "for update skip locked", we shouldn't run into locking issue with concurrent processing. Database is MySQL.

But I am still getting *"javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException"*  when multiple threads are running the below code.

What could be the reason for this?

```
Query selectQuery = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(....)

select id from tb_contacts limit 10 for update SKIP LOCKED
....
.... processing in java
....
update tb_contacts set status = 2 where id in (:ids)
```

Comment: How are you running the update statement? Please share the whole code and whole stack trace.